# How to install Netbeans 7.4 on mac os mavericks (with jdk 7 update 45 already installed)?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, java-7, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install Netbeans 7.4 on my mavericks mac os system but I get this very strange message at the start of installation :

No JDK found

NetBeans IDE cannot be installed.
Java (JRE) found on your computer but JDK 7 update 10 or newer is required.
Please download and install the latest update of JDK 7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and restart NetBeans installation.

What is so strange here is that I have already installed jdk 7 update 45 on my system, since I use it to work on projects made with IntelliJ Idea, the other IDE that I use.

Update1 : Here is what java -version gives
[image]

Update2 : System Preferences --> Java

[image]

Comment: to check whether this java lives in a JRE or a JDK, you could run `which java` (and paste the textual output of that command, screenshots are maybe cuter but don't have any added value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not confusing jre with Java development tool kit a.k.a JDK. You may have jre but may not have JDK. 
Try this and let us know the JDK version . 
Open the terminal in OSX and type this -

```
java -version
```

Comment: Aaah... you have Jdk 7 installed but it has update 6 not 10. For example my macbook has version -7 with 45.                           Dineshs-MacBook-Pro:~ dinesharora$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: But when I go to System Preferences --> Java I have the following report (see my 2nd update of the original post)

Comment: I followed these directions (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112525/java-version-1-7-45-and-mavericks).Thank you for helping me with this.